# Grails JMS Message failed to add permission using Spring Security

Tags: grails, spring-security, jms

I have a JMS Message Listner, which gets the message properly from controllers.

The method looks like

```
@Override
public void onMessage(Message message) {
try {
    def data
    if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
    data =  ((TextMessage)message).getText();
    onNotificationService.testIt(new JSONObject(data))
    }
    else {
    println "Message "+message
    }
} catch (JMSException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}

}
```

The data then being sent to the method `testIt` where I am doing my operation. One of the operation is to add permission some data which been processed from this data.
For that, I am using this -

```
aclUtilService.addPermission(myObject, username, BasePermission.ADMINISTRATION)
```

I am getting an exception here as `Authentication Required`
This works perfectly if `onNotificationService.testIt(new JSONObject(data))` been called directly from `controller`, it works perfect.

What I am missing?

Any help on this highly appreciated.

Comment: It works in the controller because you're authenticated and that's available via a thread-local, but when you do work on a different thread, there's no active authentication to work with

Comment: That's correct. My question is how add active authentication on these threads?

Answer (score 0):

If each message is to be run with the authentication of the message sender you'll want to encode something in the message and load the Authentication in to the SecurityContext (http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/context/SecurityContext.html):

```
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication
...
public void onMessage(Message message) {
    ...
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(fetchAuthentication())
    ...
}
...
// Use some token or marker from the message to fetch the appropriate Authentication
Authentication fetchAuthentication() {}
```

You could modify the strategy mode (see: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/context/SecurityContextHolder.html) if you want to handle authentication globally or inherited from a parent thread.

If you're looking to encode a token of some kind in the message consider using a JWT (https://jwt.io/)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I used this. On it, authentica

Comment: On it authentication issue gone but soon the connection pool gets exhausted

Comment: The error resulted is like this.  [05:36:04.773] ERROR org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction JDBC begin failed
java.sql.SQLException: PooledConnection has already been closed.